# Invariance of Schwartz space under unitary group of Laplacian.

Tags: functional-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions and let $H = -\Delta$ denote the free Schrödinger operator on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and $U(t) = e^{-itH}$ the associated unitary group. How does one show that $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is invariant under $U(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how the Fourier transform plays with the Schwarz space and these operators:

First you want to show this: If $m\in C^\infty$ and $D^\alpha m$ has polynomial growth for every $\alpha$ then $f\mapsto mf$ takes the Schwarz space to itself.

Now if you take the Fourier transform of your problem you see that you just have to show that if $m(\xi)=e^{it|\xi|^2}$ then every partial of $m$ has polynomial growth. This is easy; compute a few partials to see why.

Background: Say $S$ is the Schwarz space and $F$ is the Fourier transform. Then $F$ is an isomorphism of $S$ (bounded, with a bounded inverse). So a given operator $T$ maps $S$ to $S$ if and only if $F^{-1}TF$ does so.

Now $F^{-1}HF$ is just multiplication by $|\xi|^2$. Hence if $P$ is any polynomial, $F^{-1}P(H)F=P(F^{-1}HF)$ is multiplication by $P(|\xi|^2)$. Taking limits with an appropriate sequence $P_n$ shows that $F^{-1}U(t)F$ is multiplication by $m$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does polynomial growth mean the following: for all $j \geq 0$ there exists $C,k \geq 0$ s.t. $|D^j m(x)| \leq C(1+|x|)^k$? I do not exactly understand what you mean by taking the Fourier transform of the problem. Do you mean that $U(t) f$ becomes multiplication with $m$ when applying the Fourier transform? Why is that?

Comment: Saying every partial has polynomial growth says that, yes. Except the $j$ in your $D^j$ is a multi-index; $\alpha$ would be more standard notation, $j$ looks like a positive integer. Say $F$ is the Fourier transform. Then you know that $F(Hf)(\xi)=|\xi|^2F(f)(\xi)$, right? (If that doesn't look familiar you should read up on the Fourier transform.) It follows that $F(U(t)f)=mF(f)$, just from the definition of the exponential as a power series. More detail available if that's not enough, but not now, gotta go...

Comment: It's earlier than I thought - added a few details to my answer.

Comment: ah, i guess i could use the spectral theorem here somehow to make the last step more precise. But at the moment its not so clear to me how it follows from $F(Hf)(\xi)=|\xi|^2 F(f)(\xi)$ that $F(U(t)f) = m F(f)$.

Comment: just a last minor question: could it be that it should be $F H F^{-1}$ is multiplication by $|\xi|^2$? But again this is more of a convential thing i guess? Also what you describe here is more or less that the Fourier transform is the unitary transform that implements the spectral theorem for $H$ here, right?

Comment: I wasn't being all that careful - you want to say it's $FTF^{-1}$ instead of the other way around, fine. $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are so close to being the same thing it really doesn't matter (ok, your version is consistent with the things I'd written earlier. But all those things are equally valid with $F^{-1}$ in place of $F$.)

Comment: If $P_n$ are those polynomials converging to the exponential then there are some details missing in showing that $P_n(|\xi|^2)f\to e^{it|\xi|^2) f$ in $S$, for $f\in S$. I'm not sure whether that's easy, or come to think of it even true. BUT it's clear we have convergence in $S$ if $f$ is smooth with compact support, and this is enough to show that $U(t)$ has the spectral representation we want.

Comment: And yes, yes, yes, the point is that $F$ is precisely the unitary transformation that implements the spectral theorem. I tend to say $F$ is what "diagonalizes" $H$. Indeed, some would say that the whole point to $F$ is that it diagonalizes differential operators. (Very clear for Fourier series, slightly more subtle for the Fourier transform.)